# What's the behaviour of `cat | less`?

Tags: command-line, bash, less, cat

I tried to run the following command:

```
cat | less
```

I know both commands require something from the standard input.
When I run it that's what I expected: all my inputs goes to cat and I will not be able to send commands to less (eventually without being able to quit the program with the command `q`.).

This is not what happens. Actually, it works properly as long as the number of lines sent in the standard input is less than the number of lines of the screen. When the number of lines sent in the standard input became greather than the number of lines of my consolle, a strange beahviour appeaers. It seems that input is sent sometimes to `cat`, sometimes to `less`. For instance, inespectately, the letter `q` *sometims* let the program quit.

Why the reason of this behaviour that I (naively) wouldn't expect?

Comment: another interesting thing is if I do `echo a|less` it says 'end' at the end, but not with  cat|less even when it hits less, With cat|less, when it hit less it shows a colon for a prompt. Which yeah I guess means there's more on the screen. as you say. I guess davidgo's answer about buffering might explain that. BTW I notice just typing `less<ENTER>` it doesn't prompt for stdin, so it's interesting that you can echo/pipe to it.

Comment: @barlop nice comment, I guess it's related to another question I have, why `less afilename` will accept commands in the standard input, and `cat afilenime|less` will do it too (isn't the standard input of `less` actually the standardout of `cat`?).

Comment: less only accepts stdin after it has been given stdin. So for example, type cat<ENTER> you see it is trying to read input. But less is more strange. Try less<ENTER> and it doesn't read input. Give less some input e.g. a file, and then , it wants input. I'm not quite sure what's happening with less..  i'm wondering how it'd be coded, if I knew then i'd get it.. Have you seen code that accepts standard input when it runs?you'd see it enables you to pipe to it and if you don't pipe to it then it prompts you.. i'm not sure though also about specifying a filename.. how it atkes that over stdin

Answer (score 2):

CAT will accept input from stdin (although arguably it more sensibly prefers input from a file or pipe), AND OUTPUTS IT TO STDOUT

This means that the input is simply piped through cat, and then directed on to less.   Thus you can see the output in less.

Your confusions are most likely coming in with buffering.  CAT is buffering the input and will be batching it (or waiting for end of file) when sending it on to less for formatting.

Answer (score 2):

I hate myself for saying this, but

> There’s more than one way to skin a `cat`.

By which I mean, there’s standard input, and then there’s standard input. 
Or, there’s reading from the keyboard (terminal),
and then there’s reading from the keyboard.  Try

```
less < afilename
```

It works just like

```
less afilename
```

which means `less` must have some way of reading from the keyboard
other than reading from the standard input. 
Here’s another command that works, even though you might not expect it to:

```
less afilename < /dev/null
```

Look at [the `tty` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/tty.1.html). 
It reports the name of the tty (terminal) connected to the standard input. 
It works by calling [the `ttyname` library function](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man3/ttyname.3.html)
with an argument of `0` (the file descriptor of the standard input).

`less` is probably calling `ttyname(1)`
to get the name of the tty (terminal) connected to the standard output. 
It then opens that tty for reading, and accepts commands from it. 
It does not read commands from the standard input; that’s only for data.

So what we have is two quasi-independent processes (`cat` and `less`)
***independently*** (concurrently) reading from the keyboard
(i.e., the tty / terminal) on two independent file descriptors. 
This is a confusing situation, and is something of a “race condition”. 
I find it somewhat analogous to the operation of a [pinball machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinball),
in which there are many lanes, or paths, that the ball can take —
and it always takes *one*; it can never take more than one.  Similarly,
when multiple processes are reading from the same terminal simultaneously,
every line that is typed (if the terminal is in line mode)
or every character that is typed (if the terminal is in character mode)
goes to exactly one process. 
And the selection is arbitrary, not unlike the action of the pinball. 
It’s not fully “random”, any more than the scheduling of processes is random;
but it’s essentially unpredictable.

So, here’s what happens:

- `cat` reads from its standard input, which, by default, is the terminal,
  and writes to its standard output, which is the pipe to `less`.
- At some point, `less` calls `ttyname(1)`,
  gets the name of the terminal it is on, and opens that for reading.
- `less` reads a screen-full of data (i.e., 24 lines, or whatever)
  from its standard input (the pipe)
  and writes it to the standard output (the terminal).
- Then, `less` issues the `:` prompt, puts the terminal into character mode,
  and starts reading *from the terminal* (*not* from the standard input).
- So, we now have two processes (`cat` and `less`)
  reading from the terminal simultaneously,
  and the pinball phenomenon kicks in — the characters (and/or lines)
  that you type go to either `cat` or `less`, semi-randomly. 
  If it goes to `cat`, it gets written to the pipe and `less` treats it as data. 
  If it goes to `less`, it is interpreted as a `less` command.

This doesn’t really have anything to do with buffering.

Comment: Good answer, but `less` just opens `/dev/tty`: "/dev/tty: In each process, a synonym for the controlling terminal associated with the process group of that process, if any. It is useful for programs or shell procedures that wish to be sure of writing messages to or reading data from the terminal no matter how output has been redirected. It can also be used for applications that demand the name of a file for output, when typed output is desired and it is tiresome to find out what terminal is currently in use." (Posix: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html)

Comment: D'oh!  You're right; I overlooked the obvious.